# What is "FileContentIndex" folder and "read.lock" file in VS 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have been having trouble with antivirus software and the project folder.

There is a folder called "FileContentIndex" in .vs folder of the project and a file called "read.lock" inside of it. I have been searching for these two. As far as I understand "FileContentIndex" folder is created and used by VS for indexing files. However, I could not find anything about "read.lock" file. I have especially asking for that file because our protection applications mark it as a virus since the extension is ".lock".

Thanks in advance for the answers.